# How this naming variables works?

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python and I found a strange way of naming variables and couldn't understand at all.

Can someone help me please

```
x = 1
n = [1, 1, 3]
for i in n:
    y, x = x, i
```

i want to understand this line `y, x = x, i` what does it mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called tuple unpacking. The right-hand side is just a tuple; the parentheses in an expression like `(x, i)` are optional when there is no ambiguity. The left-hand side is a sequence of names that are associated with the corresponding value on the right-hand side. The statement is equivalent to

```
tmp = x, i
y = tmp[0]
x = tmp[1]
```

The right-hand side is fully evaluated as a tuple before the assignments are made, meaning you can write code like

```
a, b = b, a
```

to swap values without needing a temporary variable.

Comment: I meant y is defined as x and then x is defined as i so in the same loop x will be same value as i?

Comment: That's right. I've updated the equivalent to emphasize the idea of a tuple being created first.

Comment: thanks but if x = 1 is inside the loop after for i in n: does it make any different?

Comment: You will get the same answer but x is being (unnecessarily) redefined on every iteration.